# UIPasteboard not giving option, what to paste if it is having more than one Strings

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

I had put more than one strings to UIPasteboard, but while pasting on UITextField it is pasting only  first one, can any one tell me how can i paste all others

i am coping from first Application and pasting in other application.

```
var generalPasteBoard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    generalPasteBoard.strings = ["line1","line2","line3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own UI for providing the options in the strings array in `UIPasteboard`. There is no such thing as UIPasteboard delegate at this moment. When the user hits the given "paste", it simply pastes whatever is on top.

One approach would be drop down `UITableView` with all the choices where the user would select which one to copy to the `UITextField` (I have once implemented this option, but it's quite a long shot) once your `UITextField` becomes the first responder.

Comment: Thanks Michal for your response, but it is irrelative some how, as i want to paste things in Any other application, i don't have access of anything of other application. Cheers :D

Comment: Well there is a solution to this, but it's kind of a long shot - custom keyboard ;)